# How to array on plain JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'am not sure that it should be called normalization, but i didn't imagined better name, so the task:
I have an array of objects (let's call it **mainData** which contain `obj1` and `obj2`), one prop is array `someData` of object. The object inside `someData` and their amount vary. I want to get **mainData** with but each of containing object should have same obects inside `someData` like this:
I have:

```
let obj1 = {
    someData: [
        {
            name: 'Name 1',
            value: 1111,
        },
        {
            name: 'Name 2',
            value: 2222,
        },
        {
            name: 'Name 3',
            value: 3333,
        }
    ]
}

let obj2 = {
    someData: [
        {
            name: 'Name 1',
            value: 1111,
        },
        {
            name: 'Name 2',
            value: 2222,
        },
        {
            name: 'Name 4',
            value: 4444,
        },
        {
            name: 'Name 5',
            value: 5555,
        }
    ]
}
```

I want:

```
let obj1 = {
    someData: [
        {
            name: 'Name 1',
            value: 1111,
        },
        {
            name: 'Name 2',
            value: 2222,
        },
        {
            name: 'Name 3',
            value: 3333,
        },
        {
            name: 'Name 4',
            value: null,
        },
        {
            name: 'Name 5',
            value: null,
        }        
    ]
}

let obj2 = {
    someData: [
        {
            name: 'Name 1',
            value: 1111,
        },
        {
            name: 'Name 2',
            value: 2222,
        },
        {
            name: 'Name 3',
            value: null,
        },
        {
            name: 'Name 4',
            value: 4444,
        },
        {
            name: 'Name 5',
            value: 5555,
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: do you want to maintain the same order? what have you tried?

Comment: @NinaScholz I thought to normalize ```someData``` in all objects and then sort ```someData``` in alphabetical order(by ```name``` prop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store an array of unique names. And iterate through each data, keep the same if has the name, else add a new one with value of null

```js
const getNames = arr => arr.map(el => el.name)
const buildNewDataFromUniqueNames = (arr, uniqueNames) =>
  uniqueNames.map(name => {
    const el = arr.find(el => el.name === name)
    return el || { name, value: null }
  })

const uniqueNames = Array.from(
  new Set([...getNames(data1), ...getNames(data2)])
)

console.log({ someData: buildNewDataFromUniqueNames(data1, uniqueNames) })
console.log({ someData: buildNewDataFromUniqueNames(data2, uniqueNames) })
```

---

#### Full code

```js
let { someData: data1 } = {
  someData: [
    {
      name: 'Name 1',
      value: 1111
    },
    {
      name: 'Name 2',
      value: 2222
    },
    {
      name: 'Name 3',
      value: 3333
    }
  ]
}

let { someData: data2 } = {
  someData: [
    {
      name: 'Name 1',
      value: 1111
    },
    {
      name: 'Name 2',
      value: 2222
    },
    {
      name: 'Name 4',
      value: 4444
    },
    {
      name: 'Name 5',
      value: 5555
    }
  ]
}

const getNames = arr => arr.map(el => el.name)
const buildNewDataFromUniqueNames = (arr, uniqueNames) =>
  uniqueNames.map(name => {
    const el = arr.find(el => el.name === name)
    return el || { name, value: null }
  })

const uniqueNames = Array.from(
  new Set([...getNames(data1), ...getNames(data2)])
)

console.log({ someData: buildNewDataFromUniqueNames(data1, uniqueNames) })
console.log({ someData: buildNewDataFromUniqueNames(data2, uniqueNames) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Loop through each array and check whether the object is there in the another array. If not push that with value null. Please find a sample below.

```js
let obj1 = {
  someData: [
    {
      name: "Name 1",
      value: 1111
    },
    {
      name: "Name 2",
      value: 2222
    },
    {
      name: "Name 3",
      value: 3333
    }
  ]
};

let obj2 = {
  someData: [
    {
      name: "Name 1",
      value: 1111
    },
    {
      name: "Name 2",
      value: 2222
    },
    {
      name: "Name 4",
      value: 4444
    },
    {
      name: "Name 5",
      value: 5555
    }
  ]
};

obj1.someData.forEach(obj => {
  const itemInSecondArray = obj2.someData.find(
    item => item.name === obj.name
  );
  if (!itemInSecondArray) {
    obj2.someData.push({
      name: obj.name,
      value: null
    });
  }
});

obj2.someData.forEach(obj => {
  const itemInFirstArray = obj1.someData.find(
    item => item.name === obj.name
  );
  if (!itemInFirstArray) {
    obj1.someData.push({
      name: obj.name,
      value: null
    });
  }
});

// Sort
obj1.someData.sort((a, b) =>  (a.name < b.name)? -1: 1);
obj2.someData.sort((a, b) =>  (a.name < b.name)? -1: 1);

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic function, which does not depend on hardcoded property names (like "name" or "value"), but takes the name of the "key" property as argument, and will set any other properties to `null` when needed.

The function uses a `Map` to guarantee efficient lookup of an item in the other array, avoiding a *O(n²)* time complexity (which you get with `find` and similar methods).

The result array will also be sorted by whatever the key property is:

```js
function alignArray(a, b, key="name") {
    if (!b.length) return [...a];
    
    let template = {};
    for (let prop in b[0]) template[prop] = null;
    
    let map = new Map(a.map(o => [o[key], o]));
    for (let o of b) {
        let match = map.get(o[key]);
        if (!match) map.set(o[key], ({ ...template, [key]: o[key] }));
    }
    
    return [...map.values()].sort((a, b) => +(a[key] > b[key]) || -(a[key] < b[key])); 
}

// demo
let obj1 = {someData: [{name: 'Name 1',value: 1111,},{name: 'Name 2',value: 2222,},{name: 'Name 3',value: 3333,}]}
let obj2 = {someData: [{name: 'Name 1',value: 1111,},{name: 'Name 2',value: 2222,},{name: 'Name 4',value: 4444,},{name: 'Name 5',value: 5555,}]}

obj1.someData = alignArray(obj1.someData, obj2.someData, "name");
obj2.someData = alignArray(obj2.someData, obj1.someData, "name");

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get all sored names and map this array with the data of the other arrays or take a new object with `null` values.

```js
const
    map = (source, i = 0) => name => source[i]?.name === name
        ? source[i++]
        : { name, value: null },
    array1 = [{ name: 'Name 1', value: 1111 }, { name: 'Name 2', value: 2222 }, { name: 'Name 3', value: 3333 }],
    array2 = [{ name: 'Name 1', value: 1111 }, { name: 'Name 2', value: 2222 }, { name: 'Name 4', value: 4444 }, { name: 'Name 5', value: 5555 }],
    names = [...new Set([...array1, ...array2].map(({ name }) => name))].sort(),
    result1 = names.map(map(array1)),
    result2 = names.map(map(array2));

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```